# how to set array size of 20 mbs in C

Tags: c

How do I create an `int` array of size 20 MB?

Do I have to use `malloc` or `sbrk` or something else?

Comment: yes I mean the megabytes (MB)

Comment: Several answers provided with malloc; don't forget to free the memory when you are done.

Comment: Somebody has to say it: `ulimit -s unlimited`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`malloc` is usually a good idea if you want something like 20MB. Most stacks are smaller and will crash the program if you try.

```
int *myInts = (int *)malloc(20*1024*1024);
```

or place it as a static/global variable:

```
int myArray[20*1024*1024/sizeof(int)];
```

or with `sbrk`

```
int *myInt = sbrk(0); /* Get the current pointer */
sbrk(20*1024*1024); /* Now increase it */
```

But as the man page says "avoid using `sbrk`". The only time you should be using `sbrk` is if you are implementing your own memory allocator.

Comment: you could do it that way too, but why?

Comment: so is that more helpful? or malloc? my teacher used sbrk

Comment: I've never needed to use sbrk, if you know you need 20MB why not just malloc it or create it globally? sbrk modifies the data segment which is where a global/static variable goes anyway

Comment: I agree with Gille, and using sbrk(), you'le not be POSIX compliant

Comment: malloc() itself uses sbrk() itself.  Generally there's no need to use sbrk() unless you're re-implementing malloc().  The benefit of going through malloc() is that you can return it when you're done via free(), and malloc() can then reallocate it to some other user in the same program, even in smaller units.  If you use sbrk(), you don't get these benefits automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best choice is using `malloc`, for example:

```
#include stdio.h
#include malloc.h

int main() {
    int array_size = 0;
    int* my_array = (int*)malloc(array_size);
    free((void*)my_array);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
 int *num; 
    num = (int *) malloc (BUFSZ* sizeof(int))
```

Here you can defind `BUFSZ` can be whatever size you want